# Как изменить директорию templatetags?

Tags: django

У меня есть файл custom_template_tags.py с таким кодом

```
from django import template
from random import randint

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def random_number():
    return randint(0,999)
```

и в шаблоне я пишу `{% load custom_template_tags %}`
Но для того что бы он работал мне нужно создать папку с файлом и в директорий рядом с файлом manage.py и в папку с моим аддоном.

А писание

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
 'templatetags.custom_template_tags',
 ]
```

не дало никакого эффекта

Я хочу что бы custom_template_tags был доступен для всех моих адоннов а папка с файлом находилась в одном экземпляре рядом с файлом manage.py. как мне это сделать?

Comment: вынесите этот tag в отдельное приложение. разместите его в директории templatetags этого приложения. Для того, что бы остальные смогли использовать этот таг, добавьте Ваше приложение в INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @AndreyMaslov Я же уже писал что когда я добавил в `INSTALLED_APPS`
мое приложение `templatetags.custom_template_tags` нечего не изменилось. Я не знаю почему но тэг начинает работать только если код одновремено находится рядом с файлом `manage.py` и рядом с файлом `views.py` как только я удаляю одну из двух папок то сервер сразуже пишет мне ошибку что такого тэга нету

Answer (score 0):

Написание в Installed_apps не поможет.
попробуйте
{% load tags %}
или
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

Comment: На два варианта ответ один `is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:`